# Cascade deletion issue in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

There is my simple model:

```
class User
{
public ICollection<BusinessCard> BusinessCards { get; set; }    
public ICollection<BusinessCardExtension> BusinessCardsForMe { get; set; }
}

class BusinessCard
{
public  ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; } 

public ICollection<BusinessCardExtension> ForUsers { get; set; }
}

//it is the class for introducing of many-to-many relationship:
class BusinessCardExtension
{
public string UserId { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

public string BusinessCardID { get; set; }
public BusinessCard BusinessCard { get; set; }
}
```

I need a couple of relationship between User and BusinessCard: one is one-to-many and other is many-to-many. Conceptually they are different relationship.

Since there is double cascade path from User to BusinessCardExtension, I configure ModelBuilder the following:

```
       //just configure many-to-many...
       builder.Entity<BusinessCardExtension>()
        .HasKey(b => new { b.UserId, b.BusinessCardID });

       builder.Entity<BusinessCardExtension>()
        .HasOne(b => b.BusinessCard)
        .WithMany(c => c.ForUsers)
        .HasForeignKey(b => b.BusinessCardID);

       builder.Entity<BusinessCardExtension>()
         .HasOne(b => b.User)
         .WithMany(u => u.BusinessCardsForMe)
         .HasForeignKey(b => b.UserId);

       //then to disable double cascade deletion:
       builder.Entity<BusinessCard>()
         .HasOne(c => c.User)
         .WithMany(u => u.BusinessCards)
         .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)  
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

However it does not help. Shell returns error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_BusinessCardExtension_Users_UserId' on table
>   'BusinessCardExtension' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: Have a look at your migration if you spot cascade-delete: true twice from a property you need to remove one of them.

Comment: @dijam, yes, it helped me, thank